# Trying to send an email for first time from my local server

Tags: php, email, windows-7, email-server

I have installed easyphp and I'm trying to send an email from my computer (server).

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$message = "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3";
$headers = "From: sender@example.com\r\n";
mail('receiver@metu.edu', 'My Subject', $message, $headers);
?>
```

Error message:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "127.0.0.1" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\email.php on line 9
```

Now, do I need to install an email server? Is it mandatory?

Edit: I don't think that my ISP will allow me to send emails from their servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, PHP will try to send via a local SMTP server, which it's trying to do here.

What you'll need to do is edit your `php.ini` file, and find the `SMTP` option. Change it to read something like this:-

```
SMTP = your.isp.mailserver.com
sendmail_from = sender@example.com
```

FAQ entry **55** on the [EasyPHP FAQ](http://www.easyphp.org/faq.php) tells you how to do this for EasyPHP.

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to install an email server or configure it to use a readily existing one. From the [easyPHP faq](http://www.easyphp.org/faq.php):

> The "mail" function from PHP returns
>   an error (0) ! You need to replace
>   this line: SMTP="localhost" in your
>   PHP conf file (php.ini) by
>   SMTP="mail.isp.com" where mail.isp.com
>   stands for the mail server of your
>   ISP.

You will probably also find point number 6 [here](http://www.canowhoopass.com/guides/easyphp/setupphp.php) to be helpful.