# What email server should I use for sending emails?

Tags: php, windows-7, email-server, email

What email server should I use for sending emails with php()? ([related](https://serverfault.com/questions/214161/trying-to-send-an-email-for-first-time-from-my-local-server))

I use [easyphp](http://www.easyphp.org/) (php, apache, windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got to agree with User4283 - operating a *secure* email server can often be harder than people think... and if someone else has already done that work and made it available to you then you might as well take advantage of that. Use the ISP mail service if that's available.

Failing that, you might take a look at [hMailServer](http://hmailserver.com/) - not used it myself but I have heard good things about it. But keep in mind that using the ISP mail server will nearly always be a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for the hMailServer. I'm playing with it now. Though I wasn't able send emails (might becaouse of my ISP firewall). At least now it does not give the authentication error.

Answer (score 2):

best is to user your ISP's smtp for sending email.

Comment: It allows only to be send to the local emails.

Answer (score 1):

Try the free Google apps if you need to send less then 500 emails/day.

Otherwise I *highly* recommend the free Mailenable email server.

Comment: I can send 100 per hour from my hosting but...